# XLST 1.0 Group elements in output after changing values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Basically im a xlst newbie and have been tasked with working on some changes to a large xls file that handles the transformation of movies metadata for the german market.

The xls file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan str">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/metadata">
    <xsl:variable name="featureID" select="substring(mpm_product_id, 7, string-length(mpm_product_id))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    <Metadata>

    <some values...>

    <xsl:for-each select="genres/genre">

                    <Genre>
                            <xsl:choose>

                              <!-- Mappings for German Genres -->
                                <xsl:when test="/metadata/base/territory_code='DE'">
                                    <xsl:choose>

                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Action'">Action und Abenteuer</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Adventure'">Action und Abenteuer</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Animation'">Zeichentrick</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Anime'">Zeichentrick</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Bollywood'">Bollywood</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Classics'">Drama > Klassiker</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Comedy'">Komödie</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Concert Film'">Musik</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Crime'">Kriminalfilm > Drama</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Drama'">Drama</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Fantasy'">Drama > Sci-Fi und Fantasy</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Foreign'">International</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Horror'">Kriminalfilm > Horror</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Independent'">Independentfilm &amp; Arthouse</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Japanese Cinema'">International > Japan</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Jidaigeki'">International > Japan</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Kids &amp; Family'">Kinderfilm > Familie</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Music Documentary'">Musik > Dokumentation</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Music Feature Film'">Musik</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Musicals'">Musik > Musical</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Mystery'">Drama > Mystery</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Nonfiction - Documentary'">Dokumentation</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Regional Indian'">International > Indien &amp; Pakistan</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Romance'">Drama > Romanze</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Science Fiction'">Science Fiction und Fantasy</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Short Films'">Independentfilm &amp; Arthouse > Experimentalfilm</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Special Interest'">Hobby</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Sports'">Sport</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Thrillers'">Thriller</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Tokusatsu'">International > Japan</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Urban'">Drama > Alltag</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test=".= 'Westerns'">Western</xsl:when>

                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                     </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:when>


                            </xsl:choose> 

                    </Genre>
                </xsl:for-each>
       <More values...>
    </Metadata>
</xsl:template>
```

Issue being when the genres are transformed we end with duplicate values for example when the input contains the elements

```
<genres>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
    <genre>Adventure</genre>
    <genre>Action</genre>
</genres>
```

After transformation we have

```
<Genre>Komödie</Genre>
<Genre>Action und Abenteuer</Genre>
<Genre>Action und Abenteuer</Genre>
```

I have tried looking for some solution for this  but i have not reached the solution and any help would be appreciated.

Edit for clarification: What i need is to eliminate the duplicate genre elements from the output. Those elements can be not adjacent to each other and we cant run the output through a second transformation as we cant modify the code of the service that handles this.

Thanks

Comment: Well you at least need to tell us exactly which result you want. Do you want to eliminate the duplicate `genre` elements? Do you want to do that only if they are adjacent, like in your sample, or even if they are separated? And have you considered chaining two stylesheets where you simply run the output of your current stylesheet through a second that eliminates duplicates with Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml?

Comment: Ideally the duplicate genre elements need to be eliminated from the list, those are not always next to one another. Also its not possible to run the output trough a second stylesheet. I will update the question with those clarifications.

Comment: You'll need another XML containing the ``if``'s entries values, so you can use an XPath check the ``preceding-sibling`` nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears you are using Xalan as the XSLT processor, you can solve this problem easily by using a couple of extension functions that are supported by this processor. Here is an example using EXSLT (which you already seem to be using, judging by the `xmlns:str` namespace declaration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 

xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" 

xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" 
xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" 

exclude-result-prefixes="set exsl str xalan"
extension-element-prefixes="redirect">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/metadata">
    <xsl:variable name="featureID" select="substring(mpm_product_id, 7, string-length(mpm_product_id))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    <Metadata>
        <xsl:variable name="genres">
            <xsl:for-each select="genres/genre">
                <Genre>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/metadata/base/territory_code='DE'">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Action'">Action und Abenteuer</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Adventure'">Action und Abenteuer</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Animation'">Zeichentrick</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Anime'">Zeichentrick</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Bollywood'">Bollywood</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Classics'">Drama > Klassiker</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Comedy'">Komödie</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Concert Film'">Musik</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Crime'">Kriminalfilm > Drama</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Drama'">Drama</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Fantasy'">Drama > Sci-Fi und Fantasy</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Foreign'">International</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Horror'">Kriminalfilm > Horror</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Independent'">Independentfilm &amp; Arthouse</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Japanese Cinema'">International > Japan</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Jidaigeki'">International > Japan</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Kids &amp; Family'">Kinderfilm > Familie</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Music Documentary'">Musik > Dokumentation</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Music Feature Film'">Musik</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Musicals'">Musik > Musical</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Mystery'">Drama > Mystery</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Nonfiction - Documentary'">Dokumentation</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Regional Indian'">International > Indien &amp; Pakistan</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Romance'">Drama > Romanze</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Science Fiction'">Science Fiction und Fantasy</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Short Films'">Independentfilm &amp; Arthouse > Experimentalfilm</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Special Interest'">Hobby</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Sports'">Sport</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Thrillers'">Thriller</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Tokusatsu'">International > Japan</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Urban'">Drama > Alltag</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test=".= 'Westerns'">Western</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                         </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose> 
                </Genre>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy-of select="set:distinct(exsl:node-set($genres)/Genre)"/>

    </Metadata>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Metadata>
    <Genre>Kom√∂die</Genre>
    <Genre>Action und Abenteuer</Genre>
    <Genre>B-Grade</Genre>
</Metadata>
```

---

**Note:**

IMHO, your declaration of the Xalan namespace:

```
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
```

is incorrect, and should read:

```
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
```

Once you fix that, you can use similar functions from the Xalan extension library: xalan:distinct() and xalan:nodeset() (not that it makes much difference).

Comment: I tried this but its the transformation is returning no elements

Comment: @MiguelArriaga It's difficult to tell what the problem is when dealing with code snippets. Does this work for you? http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rM2

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michael. Actually i got it to work with your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Applying this XSLT (`style.xsl`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
    extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xalan str">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/metadata">
        <xsl:variable name="featureID" select="substring(mpm_product_id, 7, string-length(mpm_product_id))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

        <Metadata>
            <xsl:if test="/metadata/base/territory_code='DE'">
                <!-- Applying template is the way XSLT works -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="genres/genre">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ifs" select="document('ifs.xml')/ifs"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:if>
        </Metadata>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="genre">
        <xsl:param name="ifs"/>

        <!-- if if/@test=current() then we'll display if/text() -->
        <xsl:variable name="this-if"        select="$ifs/if[@test=current()]"/>
        <!-- gets all 'ifs' using previous 'genre' that have same value as $this-if -->
        <xsl:variable name="previous-if"    select="$ifs/if[string(.)=string($this-if) and @test=current()/preceding-sibling::genre]"/>

        <Genre>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$previous-if"> <!-- Duplicate -->
                    <xsl:text>Node genre=&quot;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                    <xsl:text>&quot; (if=</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$this-if"/>
                    <xsl:text>; id:</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
                    <xsl:text> is a duplicate of if/@test=&quot;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$previous-if/@test"/>
                    <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- Not duplicate + there is a 'if' entry -->
                <xsl:when test="$this-if">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$this-if"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- Not duplicate + there is no 'if' entry -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Genre>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="if">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To this source (`source.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>

<metadata>
    <base>
        <territory_code>DE</territory_code>
    </base>
    <genres>
        <genre>Comedy</genre>
        <genre>Adventure</genre>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <genre>B-Grade</genre>
    </genres>
</metadata>
```

And using that new XML file to handle the `if`s tests values (`ifs.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ifs>
    <if test="Action">Action und Abenteuer</if>
    <if test="Adventure">Action und Abenteuer</if>
    <if test="Animation">Zeichentrick</if>
    <if test="Anime">Zeichentrick</if>
    <if test="Bollywood">Bollywood</if>
    <if test="Classics">Drama &gt; Klassiker</if>
    <if test="Comedy">Komödie</if>
    <if test="Concert Film">Musik</if>
    <if test="Crime">Kriminalfilm &gt; Drama</if>
    <if test="Drama">Drama</if>
    <if test="Fantasy">Drama &gt; Sci-Fi und Fantasy</if>
    <if test="Foreign">International</if>
    <if test="Horror">Kriminalfilm &gt; Horror</if>
    <if test="Independent">Independentfilm &amp; Arthouse</if>
    <if test="Japanese Cinema">International &gt; Japan</if>
    <if test="Jidaigeki">International &gt; Japan</if>
    <if test="Kids &amp; Family">Kinderfilm &gt; Familie</if>
    <if test="Music Documentary">Musik &gt; Dokumentation</if>
    <if test="Music Feature Film">Musik</if>
    <if test="Musicals">Musik &gt; Musical</if>
    <if test="Mystery">Drama &gt; Mystery</if>
    <if test="Nonfiction - Documentary">Dokumentation</if>
    <if test="Regional Indian">International &gt; Indien &amp; Pakistan</if>
    <if test="Romance">Drama &gt; Romanze</if>
    <if test="Science Fiction">Science Fiction und Fantasy</if>
    <if test="Short Films">Independentfilm &amp; Arthouse &gt; Experimentalfilm</if>
    <if test="Special Interest">Hobby</if>
    <if test="Sports">Sport</if>
    <if test="Thrillers">Thriller</if>
    <if test="Tokusatsu">International &gt; Japan</if>
    <if test="Urban">Drama &gt; Alltag</if>
    <if test="Westerns">Western</if>
</ifs>
```

You get

```
<Metadata>
    <Genre>Komödie</Genre>
    <Genre>Action und Abenteuer</Genre>
    <Genre>Node genre="Action" (if=Action und Abenteuer; id:id0xe2bc950 is a duplicate of if/@test="Adventure"</Genre>
    <Genre>B-Grade</Genre>
</Metadata>
```

So you can do whatever you want with the found duplicates. Take care that using `preceding-sibling::` for each `genre` node makes the algorithm `O(N²)` (aka 10 times more `<genre/>` nodes will make a 100 times longer code).

Btw, having a `ifs.xml` to handle the test/values will make if much more extensible than raw-coding tests in XSL.

Comment: I suggest you get familiar with *Muenchian grouping* - see the link in Martin Honnen's comment above.